# Update contents of a comment thread without disturbing 'add comment'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how do i refresh the contents of a div 'comment thread' without disturbing users input on the text field.Like in `Facebook` comment section ? I am using `Php`, `Jquery`, `Javascript`.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function autorefresh()
    {
        var ipo = document.getElementById('commentarea');
        $('#commentarea').load('processing.php');
    }, 
    100);
```

The processing.php includes a while loop where all the div i.e. main content,like,comment is present.What i want to do is when user clicks on comment a div comes under it where other's comment are displayed and text field is displayed for users comment,similar to Facebook's comment view. How do I refresh the contents of the comments without disturbing the user's comment field.

Comment: Are you including the user comment field in the same area that you are refreshing with .load? Also, it's more work on the browser to refresh the entire area rather than just adding on new comments to the end. It may take a little bit more code, but there will be far less network traffic if done right.

Comment: fetch only latest comments & use append

Comment: ya.i have added the comment field in processing.php.

Comment: if i keep refreshing the comments section,the users' input field' value gets refreshed.So how to disable the refersh while typing on the textbox ?

Comment: @KevinB...how do i do it right? please answer me.

Comment: The right way to do it (my opinion, of course) would be to have your server only return "new" comments and display some kind of notification that the user can click on to display new comments, similar to what happens here on SO when a new answer is posted while you are on a question.

Comment: wel..thank you very much.. that seems to a good idea..! thank you.. but how do i add the new content to the existing while loop content ?

Comment: Your process should not build everything on the div every time, you just have to refresh the comments